# How to return a const char* from a function after modifying it in c++?

Tags: c++, char

I have a function which takes a const char* and adds a number to it:

```
const char* CheckName(const char* name, int number) {

        std::string s = std::to_string(number);
        std::string s1(name);
        const char* c = (s1+s).c_str();

        return c;
    }
```

But this function only returns rubbish, because the pointer c is dangling. Is there any way that I can rewrite that function?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would have to copy the data into storage that will outlive the function scope, e.g. allocated with `new`. Better to return `std::string` like the answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

`s1 + 1` (being a temporary) goes out of scope at the end of the statement that uses it.  `c` is therefore left dangling, even before you return from `CheckName`.

There is no safe way to return a `const char *` from this function.  Return a `std::string` instead (which should **not** be declared `const`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem of this function, as you suspect, is that it returns a pointer to an invalid location. That is because you return the pointer internally kept in your `(s1 + s)` string which, being declared inside the function, goes out of scope as soon as the function returns and its data is no longer valid.

The best solution is what Paul Sanders suggests, which is returning a string:

```
std::string CheckName(const char* name, int number) {
    return std::string(name) + std::to_string(number);
}
```

If you *need* to keep the pointer-based function, the solution is to adopt a C-style approach as in

```
void CheckName(char* result, const char* name, int number) {
    std::string result_str = std::string(name) + std::to_string(number);
    std::memcpy(result, result_str.c_str(), result_str.size());
}
```

This forces you to declare the `result` array in the caller function, meaning you should know its size (or an upper bound to the size) beforehand.

If you can't know the result size beforehand and still **need** to use pointers, your other solution would be to allocate with `new` inside `CheckName()`, but that is dangerous/bad territory and I would suggest against it.